# Store value from another table form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a users table and games table. Games table has user_id. The help I want is how can I change/enter the value of city of birth from the game's form which is a field in the user table. I am using the try() method to display the value of city of birth from the user table in the game's form.

user.rb

```
has_many :games, dependent: :destroy
```

game.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

_form.html.erb(game)

```
<div class="custom-hidden field">
    <%= form.label :user_id %>
    <%= form.number_field :user_id %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :city_of_birth, "User City of Birth" %>
    <%= form.text_field :city_of_birth, :value => @user.try(:city_of_birth) %>
  </div>

<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :game_name %>
  <%= form.text_field :game_name %>
</div>
```

Comment: If the user is allowed to override it: `@user.city_of_birth` in the form as predefined value. Otherwise, you can use a callback `before_save` in `Game` class and remove the field.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this question assuming that this form is meant to create a `Game`, which `belongs_to :user`, since there is a `user_id` in the form, and that `user.city_of_birth` is a string.

The traditional way to do this would be to use the`accepts_nested_attributes_for` feature of Rails.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

**However**, I would strongly suggest that you consider writing a *form object* to handle this, so that the responsibility for validating this mixed-model form is held cleanly in one place. I suggest using a gem like [Reform](https://github.com/trailblazer/reform) to make this process easier.

```rb
# app/forms/games/new_game_form.rb
class Games::NewGameForm < Reform::Form
  property :user_id, validates: { presence: true }
  property :city_of_birth, virtual: true, validates: { presence: true }
  property :game_name, validates: { presence: true }

  def save
    Game.transaction do
     user.update!(city_of_birth: city_of_birth)
     Game.create(user: user, game_name: game_name) 
  end

  def user
    @user ||= User.find(user_id)
  end
end
```

This form object can then be used in place of the `Game` instance.

```rb
# GamesController
def new
  @form = Games::NewGameForm.new(Game.new)
end
```

```
<!-- new.html.erb -->
<%= form_with @form, url: games_path, method: :post do |f| %>
  <!-- your form fields -->
<% end %>
```

Please note that it appears very *odd* that you're accepting a `user_id` in the form, but also reading the `city_of_birth` from `@user`. If the `@user` for whom the game is being created is already known (perhaps the signed in user), then it's useless (and a security risk) to accept the ID in the form - you can simply use the same method that was used to set `@user`.

Comment: Please can you explain this a little.

Comment: @Navroop Which part would you like me to explain? I'll expand the post, where required.